# Can you have different time ranges on different panels on the same dashboard?

Tags: time, grafana

I'm trying to set up a monitoring dashboard that contains two graphs. One that shows current hour transaction volumes (in 1 minute intervals from current hour start until now) and one that shows current day transaction volumes (in 10 minute intervals from 00:00 until now). I can't seem to find a way to display two different x-axis timelines on the two different panels if I create them on the same dashboard. Is there a way to do what I'm looking for?

I've tried updating the queries themselves, messing with the dashboard settings, and messing with the panel settings but I haven't found what I needed. I'm using Grafana 6.0.0

Answer (score 5):

Just found the answer in the [docs](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/queries/#query-options): Relative time. With this option you can set a timerange per graph.

Answer (score 2):

A bit too late for this answer, but might find someone who is in need of it though. You could have different time ranges for different panels on the same dashboard. I have a InfluxDB as data source and all I did was to update the Relative Time in the Query options.

[image]

In my case, the dashboard has a time range of 30 days but doing this way for a specific panel I was able to show data for the last 24 hours. The value in field Relative time should be positive (-24h will not work here).